How do I fix my ANTLR scala grammar to avoid parsing error?
I'm using ANTLR to parse scala files.
I found the grammar for scala langage here:
https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/scala/Scala.g4
I generated the ANTLR classes from the grammar thanks to the antlr4-maven-plugin.
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.antlr</groupId>
    <artifactId>antlr4-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>4.13.1</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>antlr-generate</id>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>antlr4</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <sourceDirectory>src/main/antlr4</sourceDirectory>
        <outputDirectory>target/generated-sources/antlr4</outputDirectory>
        <listener>true</listener>
        <visitor>true</visitor>
    </configuration>
</plugin>

I have a dependency on the runtime:
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.antlr</groupId>
    <artifactId>antlr4-runtime</artifactId>
    <version>4.13.1</version>
</dependency>

Here's my code to parse a scala file:
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Path filePath = Paths.get(args[0]);
        CharStream charStream = CharStreams.fromPath(filePath , StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        ScalaLexer lexer = new ScalaLexer(charStream);
        CommonTokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);
        ScalaParser parser = new ScalaParser(tokens);
        ParseTree tree = parser.compilationUnit();
        ParseTreeWalker.DEFAULT.walk(new ScalaBaseListener(), tree);
    }
}

With this input, the program fails:
object someRule extends RewriteRule {
  def divide() = {
    new java.text.DecimalFormat().format(1 / 10000.0)
  }
}

The stderr says it finds unexpected character /.
line 3:43 token recognition error at: '/ '

What do I need to fix in the grammar ?
I tried to add '/' to the list of operator chars:
fragment Opchar
    : '!'
    | '#'
    | '%'
    | '&'
    | '*'
    | '+'
    | '-'
    | ':'
    | '<'
    | '='
    | '>'
    | '?'
    | '@'
    | '\\'
    | '^'
    | '|'
    | '~'
    ;

It's a wrong solution.
First, it conflicts with the comments.
If I add ////////////////////////////////////// on top the file, it says:
mismatched input '//////////////////////////////////////'

But that's not the only problem. With this operator '/' added to the list, even without comments, I become unable to extract the different object definitions declared in other more complex scala files. I believe there's a good reason the operator '/' is not in the Opchar list.

It looks like https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/3fb73536ca8b30074e330adfbb65ddb96af5151f/scala/Scala.g4#L151-L156 does not have the / and * operators, but this isn't how the grammar for expressions should be defined. https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/issues/4043
